# Why is the probaility of finding the winner qubit state decreasing after multiple iterations of Grover's algorithm?

Tags: grovers-algorithm

Basically I'm using IBM Quantum to run the following circuit that implements Grover's algortihm by selecting the state |1001> for amplification.

[image]

This gives me a probability of finding |1001> of about 46%. When I repeat the oracle and reflection gates two more times, this probability shoots up to 97% according to IBM Quantum.

[image]

These results are essentially confirmed when I run the circuits on simulators. But when I run them on actual quantum computers, the larger circuit is returning the winner state less frequently than the smaller circuit. In fact, the smaller circuit produced |1001> 162/1024 shots, while the larger circuit returned 99/1024. This doesn't agree with the simulated results; does anyone know why this might be?

[image]

[image]